# NSFetchedResultsController deallocated instance

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, core-data

Anyone ever encountered this ?

-[NSFetchedResultsController _restoreCachedSectionInfo]: message sent to deallocated instance

While performing fetch with performFetch: using NSFetchedResultsController instance.

I'm sure the NSFetchedResultsController is retained before performing the fetch.

Answer (score 0):

That error is a hint that you are overreleasing something, probably the controller.  Check your properties and count your retains and releases; there is any extra somewhere